# Set margins on scroll event with JQuery - choppy/jumpy/shaking movement

Tags: jquery, scroll, margin, internet-explorer-11, fixed

I have tables, that i scroll on X and Y Axis (`with JQuery`). But while the tables scroll, they are like shaking.

...
So my Question is: Why is this shaking happens, how can i prevent that shaking?

```
var leftOffset = parseInt($(".tablecontainer").css('margin-left')); 
    hhOffset = parseInt($(".headsholder").css('margin-left'));
    fixOffset = parseInt($(".fixedphead").css('margin-left'));
    eisastanaYOffset = parseInt($(".eisastana").css('margin-left'));

    $(".contentbox").scroll(function(){
        $(".tablecontainer").css({
            'margin-left': $(this).scrollLeft() + leftOffset 
        });
        $(".tableheads").css({
            'margin-left': -$(this).scrollLeft()  
        });
        $(".headsholder").css({
            'margin-left': hhOffset - $(this).scrollTop()
        });
        $(".fixedphead").css({
            'margin-left': fixOffset -$(this).scrollTop()
        });
        $(".eisastana").css({
            'margin-left': eisastanaYOffset -$(this).scrollTop()
        });
    });
```

Comment: Some CSS and HTML would be very useful here. A small demo (https://jsfiddle.net/) even more...

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I'll try to provide example as soon as posible, i am newbie in this, so sorry if sumthin :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used **.stop()** - `Jquery.stop().animate();` - and the shaking stopped.